# Express app.get() How to refer to each element of an array one by one

Tags: javascript, api, express, parsing

Trying to create a script that will collect data from API and as soon it finished gathering data from the first page it must navigate to the second page.

Tried this

```
module.exports = async function (app, pool, fetch) {
    app.get('/getdata123/', async function (req, res) {
    const category_title = ['users', 'unknown'];

                        let urlApart = 'https://reqres.in/api/'; //url of page
                        
                        let url = urlApart + category_title ;
                        console.log (url);  
    }); 

}
```

and it returned the "https://reqres.in/api/users,unknown"

I want something like "https://reqres.in/api/users" than script collected needed data and moved to "https://reqres.in/api/unknown" to collect the same parameters on second page

Comment: You could do it in a loop of some sort?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by "collect the same parameters on second page"?

Answer (score 0):

You can map over category_title and it'll give you [ "https://reqres.in/api/users",  "https://reqres.in/api/unknown"] which you could then use to achieve your end goal.

```
const category_titles = ['users', 'unknown'].map(title => `https://reqres.in/api/${title}`);
```